# How can I make the background of a WKWebView transparent when used as content for an SCNMaterial?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, wkwebview, arkit

I'm working on an AR app that uses SceneKit and ARKit, and I need to display a webpage with a transparent background in my scene. I've managed to add a normal UIView to my ARSCNView and set its background to transparent, but this approach doesn't seem to work for WKWebView.

Although the issue I encountered was in AR development, it seems to be related to SceneKit. Therefore, I will use SceneKit separately to describe the problem I encountered.

To set a WKWebView as content for an SCNMaterial, I'm using a WKWebView as the content of an SCNMaterial like so:

```swift
let webNode = SCNNode()
webNode.geometry = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
webNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = webView
```

I've successfully made the background of most UIViews transparent by setting the isOpaque property to false, like this:

```swift
myView.isOpaque = false
```

However, when I apply this technique to a WKWebView, the result is a plane with a black background instead of a transparent one. I've already set the background of the webpage's root node to transparent, and I've tried several ways of setting the WKWebView's background, such as:

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```swift
webView.isOpaque = false
webView.backgroundColor = .clear
webView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
```

I have created a demo to illustrate the issue:

[image: issue demo]

In this demo, I have set the background color of the SCNView to blue, and added a UILabel and a WKWebView as the contents of two different SCNMaterials. The content of UILabel is a red "Hello World", and the content of WKWebView is a red square rotating in a transparent page. The UILabel has a transparent background, but the background of the WKWebView is black instead of transparent.

The key code of this demo is as follows:

ViewController.swift:

```swift
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var sceneView: SCNView = {
        let sceneView = SCNView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor = .blue
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        return sceneView
    }()

    lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 1000))
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")!)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
        webView.isOpaque = false
        webView.backgroundColor = .clear
        webView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        return webView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
        setupConstraints()
        setupScene()
    }

    func setupUI() {
        view.addSubview(sceneView)
    }

    func setupConstraints() {
        sceneView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            sceneView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            sceneView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            sceneView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            sceneView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupScene() {
        let webNode = SCNNode()
        webNode.geometry = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
        webNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = webView
        webNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        webNode.position = SCNVector3(0.5, 0, 0)

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        label.text = "Hello World"
        label.backgroundColor = .clear
        label.textColor = .red
        label.isOpaque = false

        let labelNode = SCNNode()
        labelNode.geometry = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
        labelNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = label
        labelNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        labelNode.position = SCNVector3(-0.5, 0, 0)

        let scene = SCNScene()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(webNode)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(labelNode)
        sceneView.scene = scene
    }
}
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        div {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
            animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
        }

        @keyframes rotate {
            from {
                transform: rotate(0);
            }
            to {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a limitation of WKWebView, so I'm wondering if there's any way to display a WKWebView in an SCNView with a transparent background. Any help would be greatly appreciated!